# LIS Linux integration Services or hyperv-daemons for Hyper-V on Debian

Tags: hyper-v

I have several Linux vm's running on a Hyper-v Host on a Server2019. The Linux vm's, are mostly Debian 10.
When I shutdown the Hyper-v host it does it so quick that I'm not really sure if the linux vm's are shutdown properly. However, on the Hyper-v server I have enabled the so called "integration services" together with the necessary settings to shutdown for each Linux vm.

After some searching I have found some information about LIS (Linux Integration Services) and other information about a package called "hyperv-daemons" which are both to be installed on Linux vm's if running on Hyper-v.

I read several articles and googled the web but I can not find any clear information weather LIS or hyperv-daemon is by default enabled and kind of plug&play ready on newer (>=Debian10) Versions or if something needs to be enabled and configured.

How can I check if I have the necessary packages and configs on the Debian10 vm's in order for Hyper-v to communicate with the Linux vm's and shutdown properly.

How can I test if my Linux vm's are shutdown properly when the Hyper-v host shutsdown/reboots?

Comment: A freshly installed minimal Linux will shut down in under a second. This is not a cause for concern.

Answer (score 5):

In recent Linux distros (Debian Linux 9/10, Centos 7/8) you don't need to install LIS by MS any longer. The kernel has support for MS HyperV devices.

In Debian you just need to install hyperv-daemons.
`apt install hyperv-daemons`

Perhaps they are already installed; just type the command and you'll see.

---

A quick way to check if a Linux machine did a proper shutdown is file system check on boot. If properly shut, you see file system clean while booting. Else there will be messages for inodes, etc.

Comment: Why don't you install `hyperv-daemons` on CentOS as well? It is already there.

Answer (score 2):

In each VM's setting there is a section titled "Automatic Stop Action" which shows what happens to the VM once you shutdown hyper-v service:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information Vick Wega. I can set everything there if the vm is switched off/shutdown. So to me it looks like that on newer linux sytems (at least debian 10 and higher) and newer hyper-v (in my case srv2019) nothing else needs to be installed on either side in order to have the guest linux os to be fully controllable by the host in regards to shutdown or suspending. Pleas anybody correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: There some additional, relevant settings  that you can enable with the same vm properties that is shown, as well as at the properties of the actual Hyper-V server. But overall, that should be covering everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether Windows can communicate with the linux-guest via powershell:

```
Get-VMIntegrationService -vmname "NameOfYourVM"
```